# Is it possible to count text in tables using texcount?

Tags: word-count

I am using `texcount` to count the words in my LaTeX document, but I have quite a lot of text in tables and want to count those too.

Is there any way to do this using `texcount`? There doesn't seem to be a simple command-line switch, and the documentation for the macros section seems rather confusing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can tell `texcount` to treat the content of `tabular` environments like normal text by including the line `%TC:group tabular 1 1` in your preamble. The `%TC:` tells the parser that a `textcount` instruction follows, `group` indicates that the instruction concerns an environment that starts with `\begin{...}` and ends with `\end{...}`, `tabular` is the name of the environment we're specifying, the first number defines how many arguments are to be ignored (in this case 1, the column specifications), and the second number defines what to do with the content of the environment (`1` tells the parser to count the text).

Parsing the following document using the perl script or [the online interface](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/online.php)

```
\documentclass{article}
%TC:group table 0 1
%TC:group tabular 1 1
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
One two & three four five six\\
Seven eight, nine & ten eleven!\\
Twelve. Thirteen.
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

returns

```
Words in text: 13
```

---

Alternatively, you can edit `texcount.pl` and change the instruction `'tabular'=>0` in the definition of `my %TeXgroup` to `'tabular'=>1`.

---

If you don't want to edit your TeX file or `texcount.pl`, you can create a new text file called, say, `TCoptions.txt` containing the line `%group tabular 1 1` (not `%TC:group tabular 1 1`) and instruct `texcount.pl` to take its options from that file by calling `texcount.pl -opt=TCoptions.txt <TeX file>`

Comment: Amazing! I had no idea about these flags for `texcount`.

Comment: If the `tabular` is inside a `table`, then words won't be counted; adding `%TC:group table 0 1` overrides this default behavior.