# Word count (title, author name, abstract, body, figures, tables, captions, footnotes, acknowledgments, references, author bios, etc.) in LaTeX

Tags: overleaf, word-count, texcount

I am using overleaf but word count option in it does not include references, footnotes, and some other counts. 
How can I count words inclusive of title, authors’ names/info, abstract, body (introduction to conclusion), figures, tables, captions, footnotes, acknowledgments, references, authors’ bios, etc. (everything). Though I have seen a couple of solutions [latex word count for dummies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250081/latex-word-count-for-dummies). Also, I have tried online word counters but they don't consider some of the things. I have tried Turnitin as well. At the end, I feel every tool gives me a different count. I am looking for a simple all-in-one solution that can count everything I mentioned above and that I can embed within my latex code. I hope to get a positive reply.

Comment: _[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ Overleaf's "word count" uses the `texcount` utility. There are a number of ways to customise `texcount`: you can find more information [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Is_there_a_way_to_run_a_word_count_that_doesn't_include_LaTeX_commands%3F) or texcount's own [documentation](https://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/documentation.html).

Comment: I do not think that it is possible. See my answer to your referenced solution. Is a figure/table one word or the summation of all the words within it? Is a hyphenated name (say Kelly-Anne) one word or two? Do footnote markers count? See x11.tex for a problematic test case.

Comment: I need to follow guidelines by a research magazine that is why I asked this question (why to downvote I am sure it may help some researchers anyways). @LianTzeLim thank you for providing me the link. I have already used it but it does not count the contents within the table. For crosscheck, I save file as text and open in word document.

Comment: See perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37777/226 for getting `texcount` to include stuff in `tabulars`?

Comment: Thank you so much LianTze Lim. I will consider it to find out the word count in tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking various word count tools and LaTeX code, I realize that the most convenient word count is through word count option in Word. I simply paste text from PDF (we can also use save as option) to MS Word. It even counts text within figures and besides other things.

Comment: When I copy, many unexpected things can be copied as well such as word/characters in tables/figures. Of course, we can do so by manually copy only texts. However, it is not easy for long text with many tables/figures.